# Locate Database in debug

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, debugging, path, sql-server-ce

I am just added database and while debugging it stops at this line.

```
   Dim con As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection(Application.StartupPath & "albumDB.sdf")
```

ERROR 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

The database is not going to bin during debug. 
I am looking for a way to have this set once it's an executable for any PC so that's why I am not using "C:.........." for path.
Tried moving to "\Resource", with no luck.

Also connection has to be reset after each error. The database has NO password protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add Data Source= in front of the file path string

Comment: thanks and your post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0712dd47-8437-4c84-b27e-2b12fddf2153/what-is-the-datadirectory-in-data-source-datadirectorynorthwindsdf) help with applying Path correct.